# Heredoc not displaying html correctly

Tags: php, html, email

I'm still green to PHP and I have built a simple mail() form using php. I have done my best to tidy the code and use the syntaxes and methods as supplied [here](http://php.net/docs.php).

However, I'm still running into some issues, with `EOD`. I have coded my `EOD` to send a few basic lines of html, `<br/> <hr/> <b/> <em/> etc.`. My issue is that the HTML is not being recognised by mail clients such as mac mail, outlook, etc.

I have tried simply using `$body = '<html></html>';` and declaring the headers as per the documentation on php. But I am still having the same issue. I have included my basic mail function below; It may be that it's a syntax error of somekind or im missing something else entirely. However, after a day or two of troubleshooting I can't seem to isolate the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// mail body.
  $body = <<<EOD
<h2>Booking Request / $date</h2>
<hr/><br/>
Last Name: $lnameField<br/>
First Name: $fnameField<br/>
Company: $comField<br/>
Title: $ttlField<br/>
Email: $emaField<br/>
Acitivity: $actSelect<br/>
<br/>
<h2>Contact Info</h2>
<hr><br/>
Add Line 1: $add1Field<br/>
Add Line 2: $add2Field<br/>
Country: $couField<br/>
Telephone: $telField<br/>
<br/>
Requested Booking day:   $daySelect<br/>
Requested Booking Time:  $selectedTime<br/>
<br/>
Interested in: $selectedProjects.<br/>
Comments: $comms<br/>
submitted: <b>$date</b> at <b>$time</b>.
EOD;

// form submission check.
  if (isset($_POST['btn-sub'])) {

    // subject & account.
      $emailSub = 'Drupa 2016 - Booking Form Actioned';
      $emailAcc = 'MGI Technology (SHCP) <testing@test.co.uk>';

    // confirmation details.
      $confSub = 'Confirmation of booking';
      $conf_sender = 'MGI Technology (SHCP) <no-reply@test.co.uk>';

    // mail headers
      $headers   = array();
      $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
      $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
      $headers[] = "From: $conf_sender";
      $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

    // mail info
      $success = mail($emailAcc, $emailSub, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
      $confirm = mail($_POST['ema'], $confSub, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
  }

  // redirect & exit.
  header('Location: prox.php');
  exit();
```

Comment: You don't send anything telling a client it's HTML. In fact, in your code you're explicitly telling them that it's plain text!

Comment: `$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";`

Comment: Wow im such a moron.

Comment: @Jon Stirling simple error, fixed. after using the correct `/` it works. lol Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Check your variables are what you expect them to be. Check for errors in logs. See if `$success` and `$confirm` are returning true or false. Do you definitely have an MTA (e.g. sendmail) installed? etc.

Comment: @Jon Stirling I had changed `text/plain` to `text\html`, I noticed that I was using the wrong slash. all is good now and the code works beautifully. Thank you for the assist.